# awk a specific column with unexpected line break

Tags: awk, df

I can't seem to find a solution for this and it's driving me crazy. I know I can use `awk` to print a column(s). I'm having trouble printing a specific column though because of the way my file system is arranged.

This is what I have when I run `df`:

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_root-root
                      36623968   4484592  30278976  13% /
tmpfs                   961312         0    961312   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1               516040    102896    386932  22% /boot
```

If I `awk` for the 1K-blocks column it returns values from other columns because of the length of the filesystem location. Basically this happens:

```
1K-blocks

4484596
961312
516040
```

**How can I list the right column info?**

Comment: Try using `df -P`. See also GNU `stat`.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: that's an answer ;)

Answer (score 6):

If you're piping `df` into `awk`, pipe `df -P` instead. It's designed to be easily parsable, and in particular doesn't break lines. Remember to skip the header line (`NR >= 2`).

If you need to parse some existing output with weird line breaks, you can tell a continuation line because it starts with a space.

```
awk '
  NR==1 {next}
  /^ / {print $1}
  !/^ / {print $2}
'
```

Beware however that there are unix variants (OSX, at least — and I wouldn't be surprised if it was the only one where this happens in practice) where the filesystem designation can contain spaces, which makes any column-based parsing problematic (unfortunately, `df -P` doesn't use tabs).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an unusually long FS name but you can try this:

```
df |grep "%" |grep -v Use |awk {'print $(NF-4)'}
```

This is assuming you don't need the title line with the 1K-Blocks.

Answer (score 0):

```
df -Pk|tail -n +2|column -t | awk '{print $4}'
```

- `df -Pk`: will list the file system.
- `tail -n +2`: will remove header.
- `column -t:` used to format the output.
- `awk '{print $4}'`: will print the contents of fourth column.

Comment: Please don't answer with one-liner commands. Even if they work, OP will have to figure out what is this, why does it work, etc. Please add an explanation to your answer.

Comment: df -Pk : will list the file system....tail -n +2 : will remove header.....column -t: used to format the ouput.....awk '{print $4}' :will print the contents of fourth column...................

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `df`, you can use the `-P` flag and pipe it into `awk` as suggested in other answers. An example to make it clear and simple: for the case where you want the number of available kilobytes (`df -k`), the following works fine:

```
df -kP | awk 'NR>1 {print $4}'
```

This tells awk to print the 4th column for all rows after the first (i.e. not the header row).

Anyway, the main reason for adding this answer is the observation that on Solaris (checked on Solaris 9 & 10), this flag isn't actually necessary despite similar linebreaks in the output formatting; the following works on in this case:

```
df -k | awk 'NR>1 {print $4}'
```