# Check if 2 directories are hosted on the same partition on Linux

Tags: shell-script, mount

How can I check if `/my/dir` is on the same partition as `/`?

This is for integration within a script. Bind mounts should be handled correctly. POSIX compatible solutions are welcome.

Comment: “Bind mounts should be handled correctly.” But what do you consider correct? Your question can be interpreted either way.

Comment: @Gilles In the original title I wrote "hosted" instead of "mounted", someone edited adding confusion IMHO. Yet my question body is clear: "on the same partition", that is on the same physical partition, whatever the path or mountpoint used to access the two files / directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best foolproof solution available in POSIX is the comparison of the files' *device IDs* provided by the [stat(2) function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stat.html).

Perl has a similar [stat function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) as *Gilles* [pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120851):

```
perl -e 'exit((stat($ARGV[0]))[0] != (stat($ARGV[1]))[0])' -- file1 file2
```

but the "POSIX way" is to use a C program like:

```
./checksamedev file1 file2
```

which source code is as follows:

```c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    struct stat s1, s2;
    if( argc==3 && lstat(argv[1], &s1)==0 && lstat(argv[2], &s2)==0 )
        return !(s1.st_dev == s2.st_dev);
    return 2;
}
```

If both files' device IDs are equal, they are hosted on the same filesystem, in which case, the commands above return 0 (another value otherwise). Check with `echo $?`.

This works well with bind mounts, but probably won't with network mounts.

Answer (score 6):

You can check this with stat:

```
$ stat -c '%d %m' /proc/sys/
3 /proc
```

Shows you the device number and where your directory was mounted.

Comment: Nice, but the `stat` shell command is not POSIX...

Comment: No? How do you know?

Comment: Not in [this list](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/utilities.html).

Comment: Oh, my bad. But next time show this link in advance.

Answer (score 6):

The following command gives a unique name for the mount point containing the file `$file`:

```
df -P -- "$file" | awk 'NR==2 {print $1}'
```

This works on any [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/df.html) system. The `-P` option imposes a predictable format; the first field of the second line is the “file system name”. Thus, to check two files are under the same mount point:

```
if [ "$(df -P -- "$file1" | awk 'NR==2 {print $1}')" = \
     "$(df -P -- "$file2" | awk 'NR==2 {print $1}')" ]; then
  echo "$file1 and $file2 are on the same filesystem" ; fi
```

Or, to save a couple of process invocations:

```
if df -P -- "$file1" "$file2" |
   awk 'NR!=1 {dev[NR] = $1} END {exit(dev[2] != dev[3])}'; then
  echo "$file1 and $file2 are on the same filesystem" ; fi
```

A few operating systems can have spaces in volume names. There's no completely reliable way of parsing the `df` output in this case.

Under the hood, you can identify the filesystem containing a file by the `st_dev` field returned by [`stat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stat.html). There's no portable way to do this from a shell script. Some systems have a `stat` utility, but its syntax varies:

- On non-embedded Linux, Cygwin or other systems with GNU coreutils, `stat` reports the `st_dev` field when invoked as `stat -c %D -- "$file"`.
- Some BusyBox installations include a [`stat`](http://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#stat) which is compatible with GNU coreutils. Others have `stat` without the `%c` option; you can use `stat -t -- "$file" | awk '{print $8}'` but this only works if the file name does not contain whitespace, or `stat -t -- "$file" | awk 'END {print $(NF-8)}'` which copes with arbitrary file names but not with future additions of fields to the `stat` output.
- BSD systems have a different [`stat` utility](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=stat&sektion=1&manpath=OpenBSD+3.8) which requires `stat -f %d -- "$file"`.
- Solaris, AIX and others have no `stat` utility.

If Perl is available, you can use

```
perl -e 'print ((stat($ARGV[0]))[0])' -- "$file"
```

and to do the comparison:

```
perl -e 'exit((stat($ARGV[0]))[0] != (stat($ARGV[1]))[0])' -- "$file1" "$file2"
```

Note that there are some corner cases where the desired result is not clear. For example, with Linux's bind mounts, after `mount --bind /foo /bar`, `/foo` and `/bar` are considered to be the same filesystem. It is always possible that the two files are actually located on the same device but you'll never know: for example, if the files are on two different network mounts, the client has no way to know whether the server is exporting different filesystems.

If the files are directories and you can write to them, another method is to create a temporary file and attempt to make a hard link. This one reports a negative result across Linux bind mounts.

```
tmp1=$(TMPDIR=$dir1 mktemp)
tmp2=$(TMPDIR=$dir2 mktemp)
if ln -f -- "$tmp1" "$tmp2"; then
  echo "$dir1 and $dir2 are on the same filesystem, which supports hard links"
fi
rm -f "$tmp1" "$tmp2"
```

Comment: Problem: `df` does not always give the device name, but sometime a symlink to it like `/dev/disk/by-uuid/ca09b761-ae1b-450f-8a46-583327b48fb4` making `df` not reliable. The only reliable option so far is using a `stat`-based solution.

Comment: @Totor That doesn't matter: whatever name `df` reports for the device, it is consistent between the two invocations, so it's ok for a comparison.

Comment: No, it doesn't work, I tested it. On Debian Wheezy here, a single `df` reports `/dev/sda6` and `/dev/disk/by-uuid/ca09b...`, both referring to the same device, but different mount points. The string comparison test obviously fails when trying with files from each mount point.

Comment: @Totor Normally you can't have the same block device mounted twice. As I indicate in my answer, there are corner cases such as bind mounts which may or may not be reported as distinct.

Comment: Yet it works perfectly on Debian Squeeze and Wheezy: `mount /dev/sda6 /mnt1` followed by `mount /dev/sda6 /mnt2` works like a charm. `cat /proc/mounts` is fine with it. However, it is only since Wheezy that `/dev/disk/by-uuid/ca09b...` is shown in `df` as the device for the root filesystem. Further attempts to mount it using this simlink or the `UUID=ca09b...` mount syntax do not end showing anything else than `/dev/sda6` in `df` (I don't know how to reproduce what it done during the boot process, but that is not the concern here).

Answer (score 4):

```
test $(df -P $path1 $path2 | awk '{if (NR!=1) {print $6}}' | uniq | wc -l) -eq 1
```

Works with any number of paths.

Comment: Parsing the output of `df` is [not always a good idea](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76258/26909).

Comment: @Totor I'm checking the mountpoint (`$6`), not the device name (`$1`), so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @JosephR It's the best there is in POSIX. n.st: why not check the first field? It doesn't matter which path was used to access the device, if it's the same mount point then the output will be consistent.

Comment: **This does not work with bind mounts.**

Comment: `df`'s option `--output=target` could make things a little more direct.